# css and html - why does a div which is float-left get placed on the line below?

Tags: html, css, image

I have HTML like this:

```
<div style="float: left; font-family: arial; padding-top: 40px; width: 655px; ">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <img src="http://www.problemio.com/img/big_logo.png" id="above_fold_img" style="border: none;"  />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; ">
        <p>
            <h1>mobile business plan, <br />
            business ideas, fundraising<br /> and marketing apps
            </h1>  <!-- font-size: 200%; -->
        </p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

And it looks like this. Here is a test page:
http://problemio.com/index_test.php

The blue B is supposed to be on the same line with the text. But possibly because the original image size is very big, it is getting screwed up in size.

Here is the css for the img:

```
img#above_fold_img
{
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

Would anyone know how to make the image and text appear on the same line?

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the `float: left;` from the outermost `div`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a width for both of the child `<div>`s. According to Chrome DevTools, the first `<div>` (with the child image) is 512px wide. 
`width: 30%;` on `img#above_fold_img` uses 30% of its parent div.
Example:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 256px; height: 256px; margin: 0">
    <img src="http://www.problemio.com/img/big_logo.png" id="above_fold_img" style="border: none; width: 256px; height: 256px" />
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 393px; margin: 0; margin-left: 5px">
    <p>
        <h1>mobile business plan, <br />
        business ideas, fundraising<br /> and marketing apps
        </h1>  <!-- font-size: 200%; -->
    </p>
</div>
```

I kept all styles inline in my example, but using CSS is better. Also, the 'b' image is 512x512px. If you can shrink it, you will reduce load times.

Comment: ah so should I not place the 30% on the image?

Comment: Should I have 30% on the div?

Comment: put width that is suitable for your needs `%` or `px`. and i would put the image width and height 100%

Comment: @trajce I am not sure what percentage the width should be. And I am also not sure if I should use pixels because of possible smaller screen sizes of some devices.  Kind of feeling stuck.

Comment: @Genadinik I added an example.

Comment: @Genadinik about the image, if you dont have margins/padding/border, then 100% is fine, since if the container gets smaller, the image will get smaller aswell (100% of the parent width. since you want to use it with smaller screens, then `%` is better option.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got it to work almost right. One question, where I use that width: 655px for the div, will that not work right for smaller screens?

Comment: @Genadinik Depends on the rest of the page. When I resize the browser window, the img (`iphoneimage.png`) is on the left, above the ad block.

Comment: @Mooseman actually when I look at it now on the phone, the blue B image is really stretched out in height. Why does that happen?

Comment: Did you remove the CSS? All styles needed in my example are inline.

Comment: @Mooseman i was trying it with the % ...I did it how you have it and it works now. :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I think just giving an answer helps but op wanted to know why as well..

You should declare a width on the image that contains the #above_fold_img so that the div takes on the same width that way you can do this

```
<div style="float: left; font-family: arial; padding-top: 40px; width: 655px;">
    <div style="float: left;margin-right:20px">
        <img src="http://www.problemio.com/img/big_logo.png" id="above_fold_img" width="154">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <p></p>
        <h1>mobile business plan, <br>
 business ideas, fundraising<br> and marketing apps
        </h1>  <!-- font-size: 200%; -->
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Also you should try not to use `<p></p>` as spaces but use `<br/>` to do that

Comment: it was there when I looked at the test page he posted...np though looks like he found his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your div to have a width of 30% and the image to have a width of 100% or 90% for astetic reasons, so:

```
<div style="float: left; font-family: arial; padding-top: 40px; width: 655px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 30%;">
        <img src="http://www.problemio.com/img/big_logo.png" id="above_fold_img" style="border: none;"  />
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
    img#above_fold_img
    {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: trying that now. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't address the widths of the `<div>`s, so they will remain on separate lines. Additionally, the image will not remain square.

Comment: sorry i placed the 100% width on the wrong div before, please check again... Keep the first with width 655px and then change the one containing the image in with a 30% width

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone The second div was lost, and the image will still be stretched because you are not defining a fixed width and height for either the image or its parent div.